# Repeat a function in JavaScript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to make a simple translator. I am just having some issues with it. For example, I want it to register the letter B and then it will write bob. Now when I write b in the translate to box (which is the normal variable) it says in the translated to box (which is theifTalk) [object HTMLTextAreaElement]bob. And in the console it says: Cannot read property 'repeat' of undefined. Anyways here's my code:

```
const theifTalk = document.getElementById('theiftalk');
const normal = document.getElementById('normal');
const translateBtn = document.getElementById('translateBtn');


translateBtn.onclick = function() {
    theifTalk.value = "";
    translate();
}

function translate() {

    if (normal.value.includes("b")) {
        var bCount = normal.value.match(/b/g)||[].length;

        b().repeat(bCount.length);        
    }

}

function b() {
    theifTalk.value = theifTalk + "bob";
}
```

HTML CODE:

```
<textarea type="text" id="normal" rows="15" cols="80" placeholder="Normal text goes in here..."></textarea>
<textarea type="text" id="theiftalk" rows="15" cols="80" placeholder="Theif Talk text goes out here..."></textarea>
<br>
<button id="translateBtn">translate</button>
```

Comment: `b()` function is not returning anything, so when you call `b().repeat` the result of the function is undefined, so it is impossible to use `repeat`

Comment: b is a function that returns undefined and somehow you are saying it returns a method called repeat.

Comment: @CalvinNunes, is there anything else I could do to make this work then?

Comment: What is "repeat" supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not returning anything from function explicitly `undefined` is returned. You have return the value from function. Also, `theifTalk` is the element itself, you should take the value from that:

```
function b() {
  theifTalk.value = theifTalk.value + "bob";
  return theifTalk.value;
}
```

You also should set the value back to the `theifTalk`:

```
theifTalk.value = b().repeat(bCount.length);
```

```js
const theifTalk = document.getElementById('theiftalk');
const normal = document.getElementById('normal');
const translateBtn = document.getElementById('translateBtn');

translateBtn.onclick = function() {
  translate();
}
function translate() {
  if (normal.value.includes("b")) {
    var bCount = normal.value.match(/b/g)||[].length;
    theifTalk.value = b().repeat(bCount.length);        
  }
}

function b() {
  theifTalk.value = theifTalk.value + "bob";
  return theifTalk.value;
}
```

```html
<textarea type="text" id="normal" rows="15" cols="80" placeholder="Normal text goes in here..."></textarea>
<textarea type="text" id="theiftalk" rows="15" cols="80" placeholder="Theif Talk text goes out here..."></textarea>
<br>
<button id="translateBtn">translate</button>
```

Comment: I guess something is missing here: `theifTalk + "bob"`, theifTalk is not a string. Ah, you've noticed already!  LOL

Comment: @Mamun That works, but just one problem. If i write 2 b's it still only says bob and not bobbob

Comment: @lasseesharp, please update the question with relevant HTML....